# Phalcon PHP - Array options to validator

Tags: phalcon, phalconeye

What options do I send to `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\` construct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for `Validator` just stores an array of options to the `_options` property.

Depending on what validator you are using (PresenceOf, Url etc.) they will have their own options.

If you create you own you can use whatever options you want.